# facebook activity in background

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, background

I am using facebook sdk to let the user post a message to his wall.
I was using the existing facebook tutorial: 
[Facebook tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

Here the main code which I use:

```
package com.greatapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /*
         * Get existing access_token if any
         */
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        if(access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        /*
         * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
         */
        if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {}
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I have extended this base code with a postToWall(String message) method. This is working fine.

I call this by an intent from an other activity. I want that all this facebook posting is handled in the background without showing an progressbar or something like that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The facebook android SDK has two facebook classes to use: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner.java

You can use it exactly the same way as the other one, just to construct it you do this:

```
Facebook fb = new Facebook(appid);
AsyncFacebookRunner async = new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb);
async.request("me", new SimpleDialogListener());
```

Comment: what do I have to implement for that SimpleDialogListener() ?

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and go through this **simple** example from facebook: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/simple/src/com/facebook/android. It explains most of what you need, including the dialog listener part.  Once you understand that code everything will become clearer.  As a rule of thumb, it's always preferred to actually do your homework before you come and post questions here, or in other forum.

Comment: you are extremly right. But I am struggling with this since 2 days. I have read the tutorial. Now I have done it by my own and let the posting run in an own thread in background. thats fine. thx